# RSpec no route matches with nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have an application (API) where I wan't to test the requests for each controller execute successfully. I have the following routes:

```
   resources :items do
    resources :offers, only: [:index, :create, :destroy, :update] do
      put :accept, on: :member
    end
  end
```

In the items_controller_spec.rb the following works fine:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ItemsController do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  item = user.items.create()


  context "GET #index" do

    it 'returns unauthorised - 401 when not logged in' do
      get :index
      # test for the 401 unauthorised
      expect(response.status).to eq(401)
    end

    it 'returns 200 and users items when logged in' do
      get :index , { access_token: user.token }

      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

  end
end
```

In offers_controller_spec.rb the same code doesn't work and produces the following error:

```
  1) OffersController GET #index shows something
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"offers"}
     # ./spec/controllers/offers_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Should the request be tested in a different way because the route is nested?I tried a number of things but nothing seems to work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's nested, you need to get offers for a specific item.

So you need to do

```
get :index, :item_id => Item.first.id
```

(or in place of Item.first, some specific item record you want to test against)